# Delete Value from array when a new spinner item is selected

Tags: android, arraylist, android-spinner

Iam creating app.In which Iam asking user its blood group through spinner and when user select a blood group I add blood groups to an arrayList  to whom he can donate blood.Like if he select blood group O-,I will add all the blood groups to array as O- can donate blood to all.Till this its working fine issue came when user mistakenly select O- and then he selects A- , so now how should I remove the previous groups from arrayList and add the groups to whom A- can donate blood
Right now Iam doing this:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                matchedGrpToDonate = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                matchedBloodGroups();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
private void matchedBloodGroups() {
        if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("A+")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("A+");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        } else if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("A+")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("A+");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        }

        if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("A-")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("A+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("A-");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        } else if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("A-")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("A+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("AB-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("A-");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        }

        if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("B+")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("B+");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        } else if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("B+")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("B+");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        }

        if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("B-")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("B+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("B-");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        } else if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("B-")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("B+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("AB-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("B-");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        }

        if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("O+")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("A+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("B+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("O+");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);

        } else if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("O+")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("A+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("B+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("O+");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        }

        if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("O-")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("A+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("B+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("O+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("A-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("B-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("O-");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        } else if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("O-")) {
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("A+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("B+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("O+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("AB-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("A-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("B-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.remove("O-");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a check in if statement that if array list is not empty clear it and add value of blood groups like this:

```
private void matchedBloodGroups() {
        if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("A+")) {
            if (!bloodBankCanDonate.isEmpty())
                bloodBankCanDonate.clear();
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("A+");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        }
        if (matchedGrpToDonate.equals("A-")) {
            if (!bloodBankCanDonate.isEmpty())
                bloodBankCanDonate.clear();
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("A+");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("AB-");
            bloodBankCanDonate.add("A-");
            System.out.println("hash" + bloodBankCanDonate);
        }
```

You can do the same for other blood groups but remember this condition is only for if you are selecting one blood group who can donate the blood.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i tried to simplify your code, so first i made groups:

```
    enum BloodType {
        A_PLUS,
        A_MINUS,
        AB_PLUS,
        AB_MINUS,
        B_PLUS,
        B_MINUS,
        O_PLUS,
        O_MINUS
    }

    private static final ArrayList<BloodType> APlusCanDonate = new ArrayList<BloodType>() {
        {
            add(BloodType.AB_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.A_PLUS);
        }
    };

    private static final ArrayList<BloodType> AMinusCanDonate = new ArrayList<BloodType>() {
        {
            add(BloodType.AB_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.A_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.AB_MINUS);
            add(BloodType.A_MINUS);
        }
    };

    private static final ArrayList<BloodType> BPlusCanDonate = new ArrayList<BloodType>() {
        {
            add(BloodType.AB_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.B_PLUS);
        }
    };

    private static final ArrayList<BloodType> BMinusCanDonate = new ArrayList<BloodType>() {
        {
            add(BloodType.AB_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.B_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.AB_MINUS);
            add(BloodType.B_MINUS);
        }
    };

    private static final ArrayList<BloodType> OPlusCanDonate = new ArrayList<BloodType>() {
        {
            add(BloodType.AB_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.A_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.B_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.O_PLUS);
        }
    };

    private static final ArrayList<BloodType> OMinusCanDonate = new ArrayList<BloodType>() {
        {
            add(BloodType.AB_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.A_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.B_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.O_PLUS);
            add(BloodType.AB_MINUS);
            add(BloodType.A_MINUS);
            add(BloodType.B_MINUS);
            add(BloodType.O_MINUS);
        }
    };
```

Then i checking incoming blood type:

```
private void matchedBloodGroups(BloodType type) {

        switch (type) {

            case AB_PLUS:
            case AB_MINUS:
                return;

            case A_PLUS:
                udpateSpinnerForGroup(APlusCanDonate);
                break;

            case B_PLUS:
                udpateSpinnerForGroup(BPlusCanDonate);
                break;

            case O_PLUS:
                udpateSpinnerForGroup(OPlusCanDonate);
                break;

            case A_MINUS:
                udpateSpinnerForGroup(AMinusCanDonate);
                break;

            case B_MINUS:
                udpateSpinnerForGroup(BMinusCanDonate);
                break;

            case O_MINUS:
                udpateSpinnerForGroup(OMinusCanDonate);
                break;
        }
    }
```

And now you can create a method, where you setting new data for your spinner adapter:

```
public void udpateSpinnerForGroup(ArrayList<BloodType> canDonate) {
        // Update your spinner adapter with new Arraylist
    }
```

Hope, this helps.